# To Calculate the unconditional mean and standard deviation of Y.

Tags: probability

On a portfolio of insurance policies, the claim size, $Y$ is assumed to depend on the age of the
policyholder, $X$ . Suppose that the conditional mean and variance of $Y$ are :
$\mathbb{E}(Y\vert X)= 2x+400$
$V(Y \vert X)= x^2/2$
The distribution of $X$ over the portfolio is assumed to be normal with mean $50$ and standard deviation $14$.
Calculate the unconditional mean and standard deviation of Y.

Comment: What is lower case $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Law of iterated expectations
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}[Y\vert X]\right] = \mathbb{E}[Y]
$$
Meaning that
$$
\mathbb{E}[2x+400] = 2 \cdot \mathbb{E}[X] + 400 = 2(50)+400 = 500
$$
Because of linearity of the expected value.
Now for the unconditional variance. Here we can use the Law of total variance.
$$
Var[Y] = \mathbb{E}[Var[Y \vert X]] + Var[\mathbb{E}[Y\vert X]]  \\
$$
Can you proceed from here?